# How to interpret 'fill=1' in this case?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm picturing a plot using ggplot when I came across this code:

```
ggplot(data.frame(Correlation=correlations),aes(x=Correlation,fill=1))+
  geom_density()+
  theme(legend.position='none')
```

Normally, parameter 'fill' would equal to a factor variable to differentiate each one from another, so how to interpret 'fill=1' in this case where '1' is a number?

Answer (score 1):

The way you posted, the fill is set to the `integer 1`, and by default this aesthetic will be interpreted as the middle of a continuous scale running from light blue to dark blue.

Allow the legend to display, and you can see the scale:

```
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length, fill=1))+
    geom_density()
```

Changing the fill from an aesthetic, to a geom attribute:

```
  ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length))+
    geom_density(fill=1)
```

Now `1` means the first color from a internally defined set of colors, in this case black, `2` would be reddish, `3` is green.

Comment: Does the integer 'fill' equals to matter?Or it's just gonna fill the plot with the same color no matter what the input is?And is there anywhere I can look for more detail on this?

Comment: You can put any number in, and it will remain the same blue (as that number will be the middle of the scale). If you change to "1" or "random-word" or "purplish", then it will be the first in a discrete/categorical scale, and show 'reddish'.  @hadley 's book is the authority - https://ggplot2-book.org/scale-colour.html see chapter 11.3